# Intellij strange compilation errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea

i forced my computer to restart after freezing and i found out that my IDE IntelliJ Community Edition, I am seeing some strange compilation errors. According to the compiler, but my application is running perfectly how can i fix it

[image]

Comment: Those look like spell check errors.

Comment: Delete the System directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#system-directory while the IDE is not running.

Comment: The fix is available in 2021.1.1 release: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/04/intellij-idea-2021-1-1/. Please update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can fix this problem by going to
File -> invalidate caches -> invalidate and restart

Answer (score 2):

It's a known issue in 2021.1 release. The fix [is available in 2021.1.1 update](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/04/intellij-idea-2021-1-1/).